# CSS Positioning Issues with Thumbnail in Slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have made the thumbnails in the attached link larger, but some elements and positioned relative, and some absolute, and it appears as those the now larger thumbs are behind something. I've been working for hours and cannot figure out how to get the full thumbnail section to show.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I know the site looks horrendous - that is how she wants it.

http://75.103.101.29/wp2/?p=11297

Comment: I'd start again and refer to a JS thumbnail picture gallery library - (there's a lot pitfalls in the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`<div class="galleria-container notouch" style="width: 800px; height: 850px;">`

try :

`<div class="galleria-container notouch" style="width: 800px; height: 990px;">`

and change your css on line 1771 as

```
.galleria-thumbnails-container {
  bottom: 0 !important;
  height: 149px !important;
}/*on line 1771*/
```

I think after this you can handle it.